# How can I filter elements with <a> links in Jquery when CSS Grids keeps them in place?

Tags: jquery, css, css-grid

So I have a basic **jQuery** filter that was filtering div nicely. However, once I added google map `<a>` links to each div it doesn't work anymore. When I filter the results stay in their grid instead of moving. So I am left with blank space between the grid elements instead of it only showing the filter results. A friend suggested I add the hidden class and that I need to change the search input to look for hidden elements but i'm confused Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".box").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #444;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">

  <input id="myInput" type="text" width="100%" placeholder="Search by 
    resort/hashtag"> </div>

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Avoriaz" target="_blank">
  <div id="avoriaz" class="box"> Avoriaz 1800m
    <br/>
    <p> #quiet #car-free #cheap #pool #france </p> <br/>
    <div class="green">
      31 </div>
    <div class="blue"> 122 </div>
    <div class="red"> 100 </div>
    <div class="black"> 32 </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="hidden" 
href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Belle+Plagne" target="_blank"> <div 
id="belleplagne" class="box"> Belle Plagne 2500m <br/> <p> #quiet #cheap 
#car-free #pool #france </p> <br/>  <div class="green"> 12 </div> <div 
class="blue"> 128 </div> <div class="red"> 79 </div> <div class="black"> 37 
</div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Chamonix-Mont-
Blanc" target="_blank"> <div id="chamonix" class="box"> Chamonix 1035m <br/> 
<p> #party #luxury <!-- #sub2hrTransfer --> #pool #michelin-star #france 
</p> <div class="green"> 6 </div> <div class="blue"> 30 </div> <div 
class="red"> 31 </div> <div class="black"> 10 </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden"
href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jackson+Hole" target="_blank"> <div 
id="jacksonhole" class="box"> Jackson Hole 1900m <br/> <p> #party #luxury 
#usa </p> <br/>  <div class="green"> 12 </div> <div class="blue"> 46</div> 
<div class="black"> 58 </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Keystone,+CO+80435,+USA/@39.5965435,-114.8968694,5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x876a5724e77c6583:0x43670c887d2ffa61!8m2!3d39.5791675!4d-105.9347384" target="_blank"> <div id="keystone" class="box"> Keystone 2800m <br/> <p> #quiet #usa </p> <br/> <div class="green"> 15 </div> <div class="blue"> 36 </div> <div class="black"> 64 </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Klosters+Parsenn/@46.8425697,7.7038304,7z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x4783580b64d6dee7:0x69ddf6d69d9d3cc3!2sKlosters-Serneus,+Switzerland!3b1!8m2!3d46.8699029!4d9.8828697!3m4!1s0x4784a882f146d7e9:0x78816e8ea23fc6cb!8m2!3d46.849215!4d9.8240089" target="_blank"> <div id="klosters" class="box"> Klosters 1200m <br/> <p> #party #luxury #swiss </p> <br/> <div class="blue"> 24 </div> <div class="red"> 40 </div> <div class="black"> 12 </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tourist+Office+of+Les+2+Alpes/@44.9625404,3.9788973,7z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x478a12bf79d10603:0x53220c91ec9171ca!2sLes+Deux+Alpes,+38860+V%C3%A9nosc,+France!3b1!8m2!3d45.0054067!4d6.1235968!3m4!1s0x478a12c27920a0af:0x6b4c6fed54b647f0!8m2!3d45.0101178!4d6.1254975" target="_blank"> <div id="lesdeuxalpes" class="box"> Les Deux Alpes 1650m <br/> <p> #cheap #party #michelin-star #pool #france </p><br/> <div class="green"> 64 </div> <div class="blue"> 94 </div> <div class="red"> 75 </div> <div class="black"> 31 </div> </div> </    a> 


<a class="hidden" 
href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Les+Menuires,+73440+Saint-Martin-de-
Belleville,+France/" target="_blank"> <div id="lesmenuires" class="box"> Les 
Menuires 1850m<br/> <p> #quiet #cheap #pool #france</p> <br/> <div 
class="green"> 53</div> <div class="blue"> 140 </div> <div class="red"> 112 
</div> <div class="black">34  </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" 
  
  
  
<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Telluride+Ski+Resort/@37.9208208,-116.7986319,5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x873ed87b70e6f473:0x38ee772171bae3e1!2sTelluride,+CO+81435,+USA!3b1!8m2!3d37.9374939!4d-107.8122852!3m4!1s0x873ed7fd24b94b9f:0x9d02e608ccfc306b!8m2!3d37.9129068!4d-107.8381813" target="_blank"> <div id="telluride" class="box"> Telluride 2670m <br/> <p> #luxury #quiet #usa </p> <div class="green"> 29 </div>  <div class="blue"> 46 </div> <div class="black"> 52 </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tignes+Val+d'Is%C3%A8re/@45.4689497,4.665585,7z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x478974b6e64a1b11:0x9b3c65ed86a37ce1!8m2!3d45.4689497!4d6.9067958" target="_blank"> <div id="tignes" class="box"> Tignes 1800m <br/> <p> #cheap #car-free #pool #france</p> <br/> <div class="green">20 </div> <div class="blue"> 68 </div> <div class="red"> 40 </div> <div class="black"> 26 </div> </div> </a>

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vail+Ski+Resort/@39.6334399,-115.3251057,5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x876a7005515dcf07:0xc9ccc01f7e9aa3c4!2sVail,+CO+81657,+USA!3b1!8m2!3d39.6402638!4d-106.3741955!3m4!1s0x876a7060c630dbdb:0xa7c2cf2d4b45ada2!8m2!3d39.6061511!4d-106.3549519" target="_blank"> <div id="vail" class="box"> Vail 2470m <br/> <p> #party #luxury #usa </p> <br/> <div class="green"> 35 </div> <div class="blue">  56 </div>  <div class="black"> 102 </div> </div> </a> 

 <a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tourist+Office+Val+d'Isere/@45.4485984,4.7408155,7z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x47890909fd5ffb93:0x408ab2ae4baa830!2s73150+Val-d'Is%C3%A8re,+France!3b1!8m2!3d45.448034!4d6.980226!3m4!1s0x47890be8d2918a3f:0xdbf52a5cc1090823!8m2!3d45.449121!4d6.9800963" target="_blank"> <div id="valdisere" class="box"> Val D'Isere 1850m <br/> <p> #party #luxury #pool #france </p> <br/>  <div class="green"> 20 </div> <div class="blue">  68 </div> <div class="red"> 40 </div> <div class="black"> 26 </div> </div> </a>

 <a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Val+Thorens/@45.2979478,4.3408875,7z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4789866002267071:0x8ec7bc6dc1eef333!8m2!3d45.2979478!4d6.5820983" target="_blank"> <div id="valthorens" class="box"> Val Thorens 2300m <br/> <p> #party #luxury #pool #france </p> <br/> <div class="green"> 53 </div> <div class="blue"> 140 </div> <div class="red"> 112 </div> <div class="black"> 34 </div> </div> </a> 

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Whistler+ski+resort+BC/@50.1130232,-127.4368298,6z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x5487232a9da252a7:0xf87ac63ef242f54!8m2!3d50.1130232!4d-122.9544082" target="_blank"> <div id="whistler" class="box"> Whistler 670m <br/> <p> #party #luxury #pool #canada </p> <br/> <div class="green"> 35 </div>  <div class="blue"> 110 </div> <div class="black"> 35 </div>  <div class="diamond"<div class="black"> 10 </div></div> </a>

 <a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Zermatt/@46.0225132,5.5052743,7z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x478f35a2292ee5cd:0x400ff8840196f70!2s3920+Zermatt,+Switzerland!3b1!8m2!3d46.0207133!4d7.749117!3m4!1s0x478f3675de88e779:0xcc169fa9e5323505!8m2!3d46.0244723!4d7.7482957" target="_blank">  <div id="zermatt" class="box"> Zermatt 1620m <br/> <p> #party #luxury #car-free #swiss </p> <br/>  <div class="blue"> 140 </div> <div class="red"> 112 </div> <div class="black"> 34 </div> </div> </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the html which contains the grid? Because we can't see it here. Also, `filter` is meant to **filter** items from a collection. If you want to do something foreach item in a collection use `each`..

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector. The `hidden` parent of `box` has `display:none` and is what you need to toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".hidden").each(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #444;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">

  <input id="myInput" type="text" width="100%" placeholder="Search by 
    resort/hashtag"> </div>

<a class="hidden" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Avoriaz" target="_blank">
  <div id="avoriaz" class="box"> Avoriaz 1800m
    <br/>
    <p> #quiet #car-free #cheap #pool #france </p> <br/>
    <div class="green">
      31 </div>
    <div class="blue"> 122 </div>
    <div class="red"> 100 </div>
    <div class="black"> 32 </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! That's it almost working now. (I upvoted your answer but I'm new). The problem now is that all the images are hidden by default now. So before the user searches the page is blank.